# Sub-aggregation Performance Questions

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Let's say I have an aggregation like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match":...
  },
  "aggs": {
    "buckets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
          "total_sold": {
            "sum": "num_sold"
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In a situation where the number of unique values for the "category" field is 100, does this query calculate 100 sums, one for each unique value, even though I only want 10 buckets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very good question. The answer is in the documentation of the [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts), but here is a quick summary.

One important parameter of the `terms` aggregation is [`shard_size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_shard_size_3), which, if unspecified, defaults to `(size * 1.5 + 10)`. So, in your case, `shard_size` would be 25 (i.e. `10 * 1.5 + 10`). This parameter defines the number of top terms returned by each shard to the coordinating node.

So, let's say your index has three shards. When the coordinating node receives the above request, it will send it to each of them asking for their 25 top terms. Then the coordinating node receives 25 top terms from each shard and it will add up the counts for the same terms across the shards and reorder them by decreasing count (default [order](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) for the `terms` aggregation). Finally, the coordinating node will return the top 10 terms (i.e. the `size` parameter you've specified) of that final ordered list to your client.

So, to answer your question, not all 100 `category` terms are visited only `shard_size` per shard, and finally, only `size` categories will be returned.